# Use trigger to delete record if two fields are null after update

Tags: mysql

I have this problem. When the user make an update on single row in the table `person_tbl` and the columns `pers_name` and `pers_surname` are null, the trigger must delete this record.

This trigger does not work. Why?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trg_person_delete` AFTER UPDATE ON `person_tbl ` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DELETE FROM person_tbl 
    WHERE pers_name IS NULL 
    AND pers_surname IS NULL;
END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on "This trigger not work"? Does it produce an error? The wrong results?

Comment: this trigger, after update manually columns in the table and commit, the row are not deleted.

There aren't errors displayed

Comment: Does it work if you remove the space at the end of `person_tbl ` in the first line?

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can't modify the table which caused it to be invoked.

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html):

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

But one option you have would be to add a check before the `UPDATE` to make sure that the `pers_name` and `pers_surname` columns are not `NULL`.

If you don't ever want to allow `NULL` values for these two columns, then consider making them not nullable via:

```
ALTER TABLE person_tbl MODIFY pers_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: You can't do this in a trigger, you must find some other way.

Comment: Tim, how to add a check?

Comment: @Frankie Either check for null in the business logic layer before the `UPDATE` happens, or make the columns not nullable.  Either option should work.